# iptables-persistent blocking any outbound connections

Tags: iptables, firewall, input, iptables-persistent

I use iptables-persistent to set firewall rules.

This is my standard configuration:

```
*filter     
:INPUT DROP [0:0]     
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]     
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]     
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2123 -m mac --mac-source XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -j ACCEPT     
COMMIT
```

Problem is I can't download packages from debian servers and ping local and external IP addresses.

INPUT is only for 'incoming' connections, is this correct?

These are the rules for IPv6:

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you've got is that you're not allowing any incoming packets.  So if you try and reach out to an external server then you can't receive the replies!

This, typically, can be handled with an "established" rule

```
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

The idea, here, is that incoming packets that match an outgoing connection will be allowed back in.

Now with *default DROP* for input chains, you may see other problems (eg ICMP packets) so you may also need to allow them in depending on your requirements.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I fount similar solution "iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT", but you was first :P (+4u).

Basically I was confused, but thx for fast 'outbound' replay without lags :)

Comment: That `OUTPUT` rule would be needed if you had a default `DROP` for out output chain, but because you have default `ACCEPT` then you don't need this.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved.

**new fixed rules:**

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0] 
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2123 -m mac --mac-source XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -j    ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want a better control over iptables, use the conntrack "--ctstate" modules. It's better and newer than "--state"

For example:

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

Comment: Better or just different? Some description of the differences might help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't claim to be an expert with iptables rules but the module conntrack is making use of the connection tracking extension (conntrack) while the second is making use of the state extension.According to [this document](http://inai.de/documents/Perfect_Ruleset.pdf) the conntrack 
extension superseded state.

`Obsolete extensions:
  • -m state: replaced by -m conntrack`

more information [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/358996/iptables-whats-the-difference-between-m-state-and-m-conntrack)

Comment: Thx 4 info, I'll check it when i will have sec.